# Calculate APR from balloon loan

Tags: mortgage, loans, calculation, apr

I need formula to calculate nominal APR from balloon loan with contract fee. The initial data and payment schedule is:

Loan sum: 10 000€

Interest rate per year: 15%

Loan period: 2 years

Payments in year: 12

Contract fee: 150€ (1.5% from loan sum)

Payment schedule:

[Payment schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM6w3.png)

Comment: 15% *is* the APR.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds....

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have specified my question and added contract fee to the payment schedule which I had forgotten previously. What is the APR now and how do you calculate it ?

Answer (score 1):

The acronym APR is ambiguous, especially given that the loan in question is denominated in Euros.  This site, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#Multiple_definitions_of_effective_APR, gives definitions for both the US and the EU. From the repayment schedule given, it is clear that:

1. The lender is charging a ***nominal interest rate*** of 15% per year, with monthly compounding, or 1.25% per month.  The ***with monthly compounding*** should have been included in the specification of the loan;  the quoted interest rate of 15% is meaningless without it.  The compounding period could only be inferred from the payment schedule.
2. An single initial deposit of $100, left to earn interest of 1.25% per month compounded monthly for 12 months would grow to 100 x (1.0125)^12 or $116.075.  The same $100 left to grow for 1 year at 16.075% compounding annually would grow to the same amount.  Thus, the ***effective annual interest rate*** for the loan described is 16.075%

Comment: This is an interest-only loan.  There is no compounding.

Comment: If the 15% were paid at year end, it's 15%. But since there are monthly payments, there's an effective rate. Same as compounding

Comment: This borrower pays 125 Euros into a 10000 Euro debt each month, and *still* owes 10000 Euros.  How could the lender  *not* be added the interest into the debt each month, the very definition of compounding?

Comment: @DJohnM - +1 from me, my comment was to Ben, as I trust your's is. I agreed with your math.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, DJohnM: Okay, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem. It's weird, not intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and pointing out that my question was ambiguous. Now i know that I need nominal annual percent rate. I have edited my question to specify my need. Also I had forgotten to add the contract fee to the loan.

Answer (score 1):

According to the schedule, the monthly interest repayment is

```
125 = 10000*15/100/12
```

The total interest is `24*125 = 3000`

Interest rate calculated from total interest

```
3000/10000/24*12*100 = 15%
```

Interest rate calculated from total payments

```
(3000 + 150)/10000/24*12*100 = 15.75%
```

15.75% can be considered as the APR

Quoting: [APR - Multiple definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#Multiple_definitions_of_effective_APR)

- Laws vary as to whether fees must be included in APR calculations.